# How to convert Rancilio Classe 7 USB Espresso Machine from 3 phase to single phase system

Tags: electrical, wiring, boiler

I have a Rancilio Classe 7 USB Espresso Machine that is setup for 3-phase power and I'd like to convert it to single-phase power.

Is this possible and if so, what do I need to do it?

[Rancilio Web Site](https://www.ranciliogroup.com/rancilio/classe-7/classe-7-usb/)

Comment: USB as in the computer interface? If not, please [edit] your post to indicate what that means. Also, what's Rancolio? If there's a specific model number, including that will help a lot, too. Remember, you're talking to an international audience and not everyone knows the brand names in your country. (Reminder for those of us in the USA, too!)

Comment: Buy a single to 3 phase converter or buy a single phase coffee machine.

Comment: This unit appears to be a 3-phase only model.  Are you sure you don't have 3-phase power available?  This is a commercial-duty model and it's common to have 3-phase available in areas where there are commercial electricity customers.

Comment: @FreeMan the "USB" is just part of the name of the machine. It's just a commercial espresso machine with several boilers and pumps. It does seem the machine may have a USB interface for firmware updates, but that should not have any impact on the power supply.

Comment: **Please post the schematic** or a link to it.  The link you provided has only a sales brochure; technical docs are behind a loginwall only you can get past.  Is there anything else you're not telling us, like maybe that you're in North America?

Comment: Thanks, @PhilippNagel. I was going to question a 3-phase powered USB port...

Comment: You need to find a Rancilio tech. There's a brain that controls dosing and probably temperature. There's a boiler or two that ought to have a simple heating element. I don't know why this couldn't be hacked to normal power. The devil would be in the details.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and can you post technical docs for this machine?